# How to use AWS(Amazon Web Services) EC2 DescribeInstanceStatus API Request in RestClient (Chrome Extention)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I am new to AWS and working on an application in which I have to display different Metrics about my AWS EC2 instance Health Like CPU usage and Memory and Running Processes info. I am trying to perform the Get Request from a REST client (Chrome Extention) for clarity of the function of this API exposed by AWS.

```
https://dns.regionxx.ec2.amazonaws.com/?
Action=DescribeInstanceStatus
&AWSAccessKeyId=0GS7553JW74RRM612K02EXAMPLE
&Timestamp=1397109362
&Signature=lBP67vCvGlDMBQ1dofZxg8E8SUEXAMPLE
&SignatureVersion=2
&SignatureMethod=HMAC-SHA1
```

REST Client Support OAuth 1.0 is this an issue because AWS is supporting Signature Version 2 and 4.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the straight way with Signatures but why not use one of the existing SDKs like [boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (Python), [Ruby AWS SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/) or the [Java AWS SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/). These SDKs take care all of the authentication/authorization mechanism and you just need provide your `aws_access_key_id` and your `aws_secret_access_key`

For example with boto you can do something like this:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1",
   aws_access_key_id='<key>',
   aws_secret_access_key='<secret>')

reservations = conn.get_all_instances

for reservation in reservations:
    for instance in reservation:
        print instance.status
```

Or you can use the EC2 command line API http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351 :

```
 ec2-describe-instance-status <instances->
```

Or you can use the [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
 aws ec2 describe-instance-status <instance id>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rico I have get this working using AWS android sdk :)

Comment: Surely writing your own wrapper is a much better learning experience.